# Golang Gorm Automigrate not create filed type "time"

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

My struct looks like:

```
type AdvertContent struct {
    Id          string     `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;type:uuid;default:uuid_generate_v4()" json:"id" example:"4ff8eb91-640b-4e26-a50f-3bcd1f933d0c"`
    FromTime    *time.Time `gorm:"column:from_time;type:time;" json:"fromTime,omitempty" example:"HH:MM"`                                            
    ToTime      *time.Time `gorm:"column:to_time;type:time;" json:"toTime,omitempty" example:"HH:MM"`                                            
} //@name AdvertContent

func (this AdvertContent) TableName() string {
    return "advert_content"
}
```

When I use gorm.AutoMigrate, table fields `from_time` and `to_time` created with type `timestampz`, not `time`.

Gorm debug mode:

```
CREATE TABLE "advert_content" ("id" uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),"from_time" timestamptz,"to_time" timestamptz)
```

How can I create table with time type fields?

Comment: I think [this issue](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3455) might help - try `time(3)`. Note that I'm not sure if this will work with a `time.Time` (see [this comment](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Time) in the underlying `jackc/pgtype` library: "Other time and date types in pgtype can use time.Time as the underlying representation. However, pgtype.Time type cannot due to needing to handle 24:00:00. time.Time converts that to 00:00:00 on the following day.").

Answer (score -1):

> when using specified database data type, it needs to be a full
> database data type, for example: MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
> AUTO_INCREMENT

You should use the database data type like this

Comment: Please add further information - [`time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) is a valid PostgreSQL (and ISO SQL) data type so it's not clear what you are suggesting. When quoting its beneficial to link to [the source](https://gorm.io/de_DE/docs/models.html#Fields-Tags).

Comment: I remember that time.Time not fit with time type in database. So when declare like that, should use this:
    ToTime      *time.Time `gorm:"column:to_time;type:TIME;" json:"toTime,omitempty" example:"HH:MM"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).